# Why doesn't updating a reference update the object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, crud

I have a project with Entity Framework repository pattern to manage objects in a database. I'm wondering why doesn't an object update by passing a new object's reference to it. (question may be a bit inaccurate, but you'll get the picture with the code)
My update method is the following:

```
public void UpdateMyEntity(MyEntity myEntity)
{
    MyEntity oldMyEntity = context.MyEntities.Where(m => m.Id == myEntity.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    oldMyEntity = myEntity;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now I have checked that properties on `oldMyEntity` are updated to match those on `myEntity`, so I could assume that the object in the database gets updated. For some reason this is not the case. If I change my code to following:

```
public void UpdateMyEntity(MyEntity myEntity)
{
    MyEntity oldMyEntity = context.MyEntities.Where(m => m.Id == myEntity.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    oldMyEntity.MyProperty = myEntity.MyProperty;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The object is updated as it should.
**Question:** Why doesn't passing the whole object work? It would be a lot more efficient to pass the whole object and not all properties one by one.

Sorry for the verbose question and thanks for your answers.

Comment: oldMyEntity is just a variable, not some permanent tether to the object returned from the data context. What's odd is why you would think overwriting the entire variable would behave differently. What brought you to your original conclusion?

Comment: Why *would* updating the reference update the object?  If you edit your listed address in the yellow pages from 123 Fake St. to 987 Other Ln does it mean the house at 123 Fake St. gets picked up and moved to 987 Other Ln. automatically?  Editing an address to another address isn't going to affect either objects referred to by either address.

Comment: I get the point, but now I'm confused. Then why does the latter code example update the object?

Comment: Regarding the EF-specific question, what you may be wanting to do here is to [Attach](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/attach-disconnected-entity-graph.aspx) your 'myEntity' object by its key so that EF can detect the changes and save them.  The exact details of how you do this depend on the lifetime of your context and where your 'myEntity' came from, but this might point you in the right direction.

Comment: In NHibernate, you can achieve that by updating the first level cache. Not sure if it works this way in EF...

Comment: @Sami Why does mutating the object that is referred to by an address you have to that object actually mutate that object?  Because you mutated the object.  When you mutate the object it mutates the object.  When you mutate the reference it mutates the reference.  Mutating either one of those two things doesn't mutate the other.

Comment: In the first case, it's as though you never called `MyEntity oldMyEntity = context.MyEntities.Where(m => m.Id == myEntity.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    oldMyEntity = myEntity;`, because you immediately change what `oldMyentity` refers to (on the next line). So, `oldMyEntity` no longer refers to what you retrieved form the context.  In the second case, you altered what was retrieved from the context--so that the context is aware of the change and the update is saved.

Comment: @Servy Did I get this now, using your previous house as an example: If I declare a `var House = aLittleRedCottage` and after that `House = aCottageNextToTheRedOne` I change the variable's reference to a whole other house and the red cottage stays as it is. Instead `House.DoorKnob = aCottageNextToTheRedOne.DoorKnob` would change the little red cottage's doorknob to match the other?

Comment: @Servy Thanks.. I feel enlightened, yet a bit embarrased ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens in your first code snippet is not an update of a by-reference object, it is an update of a reference to an object, while the object itself remains unchanged.

Here is what happens:

- First line gets `MyEntity` object from the `context`.
- Second line replaces the reference to that object with a reference to another object.
- The object that you have just retrieved is no longer accessible directly, and it has not been modified.
- Context has no changes to save, because the object retrieved from `context` remains unmodified.

Here is an illustration: before reassignment object references look like this:

[image: Before assignment]

After the assignment, it looks like this:

[image: After the assignment]

In contrast, your second code snippet modifies the original object given to you by the `context`. This object is tracked, so setting new values to its properties results in an update at the time that you save changes:

[image: Assigning a property]

Answer (score 1):

You almost answer the question yourself.

oldMyEntity is a reference to an object - when you do the assignment

```
oldMyEntity = myEntity;
```

you change the reference to point to another object and the previous reference is lost - hence you are never changing any values and there are no changed values to save.

Your second example works because you keep the reference to the object you load from your context and change the value in that particular object to something else